# Are OS X installers up-to-date with all the security updates?

Tags: macos

Recently I upgraded to El Capitan just to see a couple of software updates available in the App Store a few days after the installation took place. So I wonder is the El Capitan installer up-to-date with the latest security updates? Or for that matter any application released by Apple.

My concern that one’s sensitive information might be compromised with vulnerabilities like fake updates or things like the program [FinFisher](http://picturesdotnews.com/2015/09/15/wikileaks-releases-finfisher-files-to-highlight-government-malware-abuse/), or in places with public internet connections.

Comment: There are always security updates from Apple but you should have them when you install all updates for MacOS X. The app updates are related to (thirdparty) apps and may contain bugfixes and compability fixes for ElCapitan but you can read all the changelogs.

Comment: Generally there is also malware for Mac OS X and Gatekeeper is not as secure as advertised. There may be 0days but this happens with all OS. You should always have security solutions like firewall and antivirus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update After Installing OS X

The OS X installer from the Mac App Store does not always include the latest security updates; be sure to run [Software Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338) after installing.

#### Best Defence

It is not unreasonable to assume the latest version of OS X and any third party products contain bugs and security vulnerabilities. Ideally, the latest version is more secure than the previous versions.

As a user, your best defence is to update your software as updates become available and to favour third party developers who actively address security concerns.

Apple offers the following [security advice](https://www.apple.com/support/security/):

> ### Technical Support
>
> Keeping your software up-to-date is one of the most important things you can do to maintain your Apple product's security. Instructions on how to update your Apple products can be found below:
>
> - [Update OS X and App Store apps on your Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338)
> - [Update your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch iOS software](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4623)
> - …

Apple provides a [security updates](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201222) page:

> ### Apple security updates
>
> This document outlines security updates for Apple products.
>
> For the protection of our customers, Apple does not disclose, discuss or confirm security issues until a full investigation has occurred and any necessary patches or releases are available. To learn more about Apple Product Security, see the Apple Product Security website.
>
> This document describes recent updates and releases.

### Found a problem? Contact Apple!

If you have specific security concerns, you can report these to Apple directly. Apple's [security page](https://www.apple.com/support/security/) explains how to contact them privately.